# How to enable Google Cloud Secrets Manager using gcloud command line interface?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I have started a Google Cloud Account and I want to access and use Google Secret Manager. How can I enable Google Secret Manager API using gloud command line interface ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Find the service name by using `gcloud services list --available`

   ```
   gcloud services list --available | grep Secret
   ```
2. Enable API using `gcloud services enable`:

   ```
   gcloud services enable secretmanager.googleapis.com
   ```